# Select Distinct Records from two tables

Tags: sql-server

two tables (MasterTable with columns ID,Name) DetailTable with Columns (MasterID,Status)
now the records are showing like if i join the two tables and put query like

```
SELECT dbo.testMaster.Name,testDetail.Status
FROM   dbo.testDetail 
INNER JOIN dbo.testMaster ON dbo.testDetail.testID = dbo.testMaster.ID
```

it shows the following result

```
khalid      Pass
Khalid      WithDraw
Khalid      Fail
Hamid       Fail
Hamid       WithDraw
Mike        WithDraw
```

i want to select for khalid if he has "pass" value den it should skip WithDraw and fail for him.
for Hamid we have two records but the priority should go for the withdraw so it should skip Fail for hamid. Mike has only one record so it should select his record.

result should be like

```
Khalid Pass
Hamid WithDraw 
Mike WithDraw
```

Comment: You are apparently using SQL Server, why did you tag this also with `oracle`

Comment: we have both sql and oracle databases. These databases are sync. anyways thankss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dbo.testMaster.Name, 
       case min(case testDetail.Status 
                     when 'Pass' then 1 
                     when 'WithDraw' then 2 
                     when 'Fail' then 3
                end)
            when 1 then 'Pass'
            when 2 then 'WithDraw'
            when 3 then 'Fail'
       end
FROM   dbo.testDetail 
INNER JOIN dbo.testMaster ON dbo.testDetail.testID = dbo.testMaster.ID
GROUP BY dbo.testMaster.Name;
```

You may use CASE WHEN to convert string representation of the status to a number and get the minimal status for each Name. Then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
    dbo.testMaster.Name
    ,testDetail.Status
    ,ROWN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.testMaster.Name ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN testDetail.Status = 'Pass' THEN 3
        WHEN testDetail.Status = 'WithDraw' THEN 2
        WHEN testDetail.Status = 'Fail' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END DESC
    )

FROM dbo.testDetail
JOIN dbo.testMaster
    ON dbo.testDetail.testID = dbo.testMaster.ID) a
WHERE ROWN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Case statement`** to assign the **priority** and pick the min one for all the users. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #result
  (
     NAME VARCHAR(50),
     stat VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #result
VALUES      ('khalid','Pass'),
            ('Khalid','WithDraw'),
            ('Khalid','Fail'),
            ('Hamid','Fail'),
            ('Hamid','WithDraw'),
            ('Mike','WithDraw')

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT CASE stat
                  WHEN 'pass' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'WithDraw' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
                END priority,
                *
         FROM   #result)
SELECT a.NAME,
       a.stat
FROM   cte a
       JOIN(SELECT Min(priority) priority,
                   NAME
            FROM   cte
            GROUP  BY NAME) b
         ON a.priority = b.priority
            AND a.NAME = b.NAME
```

**Output**

```
name    stat
-----   --------
Hamid   WithDraw
khalid  Pass
Mike    WithDraw
```